# Add a new property to an ASP.NET dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I need to add a new property to asp.net dropdownlist called ScoreTitle. It will only accepts 4 values and I need intellisense to show those 4 values (e.g Value1, Value2,Value3, and Value4).

```
public class ScoreDropDownList : DropDownList
    {
        private string _scoreTitle;

        public string ScoreTitle
        {
            get
            {
                return _scoreTitle;
            }
            set
            {
                _scoreTitle = value;
            }
        }


        public ScoreDropDownList() : base()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString()));
            }
        }
}
```

markup:

```
<mobile:ScoreDropDownList ID="ddlTidiness" ScoreTitle="Value1" runat="server" CssClass="input-mini inline" />
```

How can I add the scoretitle property and make the 4 values appear when I am setting the the scoretitle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make score title an enum Type.

```
public enum ScoreTitle {
    None,
    Win,
    Loss,
    Deuce
}
```

Then

```
    public ScoreTitle ScoreTitle
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Comment: We answered in perfect sync :)

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to create a enum if you want to restric valid options. It won't work for a string since it can take any value.

```
public enum ScoreTitleTypes
{
    Value1,
    Value2,
    Value3,
    Value4
}

public ScoreTitleTypes ScoreTitle { get; set; }
```

Doing `ScoreTitle.ToString()` will give you enum value name.